# Tell difference between Vista and XP [C]

Tags: c, api

Is their a way in C to diferentiate between Vista and XP.
Reason being is the the path I use is different in both.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the version of your Windows OS by calling [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx).

```
OSVERSIONINFO vi;
vi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof vi;
GetVersionEx(&vi);

if (vi.dwMajorVersion >= 6)
    // Windows Vista or newer
else
    // Windows XP or older
```

Comment: It only tells difference between XP's

Comment: I'm fairly sure it does tell the difference between different versions correctly.

I think `5.something` is XP, `6` is Vista and `6.1` is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have platform specific paths hard-coded into your application. There are environment variables for these things.

Open up a command prompt and type "set" to view a list of them. Several of these have been standard since Windows 95. Important environment variables to note are...

- HOME
- APPDATA
- ProgramFiles
- SystemRoot
- ALLUSERSPROFILE

So for example...

```
    char * path;
    path = getenv("HOME");
    printf(path);
```

Have a poke around your target versions of windows to see what variables are common between the two.

edit: python has made me lazy with string manipulation, fixed example code.

Comment: Also worth considering [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx).